# hexidecimal code for 10% transparency in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Id like to take a black background color and give it 10% opacity, what is the hexidecimal code for this in android?

Answer (score 3):

0xAARRBBGG, AA is the alpha channel which determines transparency. 00 is fully transparent, FF is fully opaque. 10% would be about 0x19.